# not getting to onNewIntent after tapping to another NFC enabled device.(android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nfc, onnewintent

The main problem is that we are unable to go to onNewIntent() when i tap my phone with other NFC enabled phone(NFC is ON).
Under no circumstances other than the main intent, i am unable to reach onNewIntent. I have tried all the three filters NDEF,TECH, TAG.

```
package com.example.nfctry;

import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
NfcAdapter adapter;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
boolean writeMode;
Tag myTag;
Context ctx;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ctx = this;

    adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
    tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] {tagDetected};

    onNewIntent(getIntent());



}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,""+intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // getIntent() should always return the most recent
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        myTag= intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        Toast.makeText(this,"DETECTED muahhhhh"  + myTag.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

and in android mainfest i have added the intentfilters as well.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.nfctry"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nfctry.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: check here [sample](https://github.com/welsinga/sample_nfc)

Comment: Hi Michael, Your code is working but my NFC card uses NFCA technology due to which the toast shows "Card Type Not Supported". What can I do to add this type?

Answer (score 2):

It's indepent off which TAG filter you use.  Your `onNewIntent` only get's called when an `intent` is called using the `launchMode`: `singleTop` or `singleTask` and ofcourse when you call it yourself. When your application is in the front it doesn't catch the NDEF/TECH/TAG discovery. You need to use `ForegroundDispatching` to catch the tag discovery events in your current app.

When your `ForegroundDispatch` catch the event and you use `PendingIntent.getActivity` with the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in your `PendingIntent` it will call `onNewIntent`.

You should enable the `ForegroundDispatch` in `onResume`:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    PendingIntent pendingIntent     = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),0);     
    IntentFilter[] intentFilters    = { new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED) };      

    adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(   this,
            pendingIntent, 
            intentFilters,
            new String[][]{
            new String[]{"android.nfc.tech.NfcA"}
        });     
}
```

And disable it in `onPause`:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (adapter != null) 
    {
        try {
            adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
        } 
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

To catch the TAG event in your current code with `ForegroundDispatch` it will be something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    NfcAdapter adapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
    boolean writeMode;
    Tag myTag;
    Context ctx;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ctx = this;
        adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        onNewIntent(this.getIntent());      
    }


    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent data) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,""+intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        // getIntent() should always return the most recent
        if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            myTag= intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            Toast.makeText(this,"DETECTED muahhhhh"  + myTag.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }   

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        PendingIntent pendingIntent     = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),0);     
        IntentFilter[] intentFilters    = { new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED) };      

        adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(   this,
                pendingIntent, 
                intentFilters,
                new String[][]{
                new String[]{"android.nfc.tech.NfcA"}
            });     
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (adapter != null) 
        {
            try {
                adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
            } 
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
            }
        }
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also note that you should add the NFC user permissions in your manifest.

Comment: thanks, i got the error. but now whenever i am trying to fetch the ID, everytime i am getting a different ID.                         NdefMessage[] msgs = getTechMessages(getIntent());    NdefRecord record = msgs[0].getRecords()[0];
byte[] payload = record.getId();

Comment: payload is giving "null", whereas getID() is givng some random values of sort "[B@426fd2a0". We dont have data in our nfc tag, the main aim is just to fetch a unique ID.

Comment: `[B@426fd2a0` is not the real ASCII output. You should print it with `new String(payload)`.

Comment: You should't also get the ID of the NDEF record because it doesn't return the ID of the device. You should use `myTag.getId()`. If you use HCE at the other side also note that the UID is different every transaction. It's randomly generated each transaction.